# wp.setOptions of the XML-RPC API does not appear to work

Tags: xml-rpc

It seems to me that the XML-RPC API command `wp.setOptions` is not working. For example if I send this information:

```
array(
    "users_can_register" => array(
        "desc" => "Allow new users to sign upppp",
        "readonly" => false,
        "value" => 0
    )
)
```

It will set the option to this value:

```
array(
    "users_can_register" => array(
        "desc" => "Allow new users to sign up",
        "readonly" => false,
        "value" => "1"
    )
)
```

Similarly, whatever value I try to set to `thumbnail_size_w`, the `value` is always 1 instead of 150 or whatever I tell it to be.

You can view the generated XML-RPC for a request where I try to change the value of `users_can_register` here:

```
<methodCall>
 <methodName>wp.setOptions</methodName>
 <params>
  <param>
   <value>
    <i4>1</i4>
   </value>
  </param>
  <param>
   <value>
    <string>username</string>
   </value>
  </param>
  <param>
   <value>
    <string>password</string>
   </value>
  </param>
  <param>
   <value>
    <struct>
     <member>
      <name>users_can_register</name>
      <value>
       <struct>
        <member>
         <name>desc</name>
         <value>
          <string>Allow new users to sign up</string>
         </value>
        </member>
        <member>
         <name>readonly</name>
         <value>
          <boolean>0</boolean>
         </value>
        </member>
        <member>
         <name>value</name>
         <value>
          <i4>0</i4>
         </value>
        </member>
       </struct>
      </value>
     </member>
    </struct>
   </value>
  </param>
 </params>
</methodCall>
```

. Note that I've tried different data types for `value`, not just the ones in this sample request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the send and response data formats.

(The format you are specifying to send with is the response format.)

You probably need to just send the value as:

```
array("users_can_register" => "1");
```